# Symfony 4 : JS and CSS compiled with Webpack return 404

Tags: symfony, nginx, webpack, http-status-code-404, symfony4

I'm building a project with Symfony4 and VueJs, hosted by nginx server and run with Docker. My templates are OK but css and js files are in 404.

Here's my nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name symfony.local;
    root /var/www/myproject/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

I configured my webpack file :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .setPublicPath('/build')
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
  .enableBuildNotifications()
  .enableSassLoader()
  .enableVueLoader();
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Css and JS files are in directory `assets\js\*` and `assets\css\*` and when i compile with `yarn encore dev` my builded files are in `public\build\app.js` and `public\build\app.css`
In template base.html.twig :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
 {% endblock %}
```

And

```
{% block javascripts %}
  {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Files are compiled as well but I have error 404 for app.js and app.css.
I've made like it's explained in https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html
So i don't understand what is missing.

Thank you :)

Comment: EDIT : i have try to add : 

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|eof|woff|ttf)$ {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it was in docker-compose.yml :
In container nginx, i have forgotten to mount in volume the path to my application, it was only for PHP container

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: dso_nginx
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    depends_on:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./docker/nginx/default.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
        - ".:/var/www/my-symfony-project:ro"
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    env_file:
        - .env
    environment:
        - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```